# Java, JSON - Decode a simple two dimensional array of ints

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to decode a simple two dimensional array of ints I'm getting from javascript, but can't figure it out.

I've tried to use Gson, but couldn't figure out what is the class of the array:

```
int[][] newMap;
Gson gson = new Gson();
newMap = gson.fromJson (req.getParameter("map"), ?????);
```

**Update**: more info

I'm sending a simple 2D array from javascript. that's pretty much the relevant code:

```
var mapData = new Array(30);
for ( var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++ ){
     mapData[i] = new Array(30);
}
......
$.post('/create_map', { map : JSON.stringify(mapData)  } )
```

in between i'm populating with integers. i just want to send to a servlet and have a 2D array in java

Comment: Would you please post more information, what kind of data it is and what kind of data format you want.

Comment: what req.getParameter("map") will return

Comment: What does `req.getParameter("map")` return?

Comment: Step 1: Post actual JSON you want to parse. Step 2: Show what you've tried and failed. Step 3: Get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this if you want:-

```
int[][] dummy = new int[0][0];  // The same type as your "newMap"
int[][] newMap;
Gson gson = new Gson();
newMap = gson.fromJson(req.getParameter("map"), dummy.getClass());
```

Comment: where? and what did you put that you got that exception? Cuz only after trying that code, I've posted it here.

Comment: @R.J nevermind, it was my mistake. So i got your code to work. But is that really the best solution?

Comment: well it may not be the best solution, but for this moment, it seems to be. I've myself not ventured into `GSON` that much, but hopefully, later when I do, will post a better solution here.